# getting corruption issue in the newer releases of docx4j. I am currently running 3.3.6

Tags: java, docx4j

https://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/corruption-issue-using-getdocumentmodel-getsections-t2627.html

As mentioned in the above link, I have updated docx4j version to 3.3.6. It solved the problem in the document.xml namespaces issue. But in commentspart and footnotespart it is still removing mc:ignorable attribute and changing the namespaces.

Is there any solution for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link you give is not helpful.  You'll need to post steps to reproduce.  If the problem occurs with loading/saving some particular document, then attach that docx.

Comment: Thanks for replying, @JasonPlutext. The problem was, the way I'm adding the bookmarks to comment paragraphs. Microsoft word is expecting a sequential order w:id for both bookmarks and comments together. Now, I have removed the part of adding bookmarks to comment paragraphs, so the issue is not occurring.